# JavaScript: Why can't you update looping variable from external variable

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop, timing, event-loop

I was playing around but I don't understand why this won't work? In theory, I thought it would but it just goes into an endless loop. **Don't run it, it will most likely lock up your computer.**

```
glb = "original";

async function wait() {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
    glb = "updated";
}

function f() {
    wait();
    var glb2 = "original";
    while (glb2 == "original") {
        glb2 = glb;
        console.log("####  glb:" + glb);
    }
    console.log("#### DONE  glb:" + glb);
}

f();
```

Why does glb2 never get updated?

Thanks!

Comment: Because nothing but the loop executes code until the function it is in returns... which won't happen until the loop stops.

Comment: Right.  `async` functions are not multithreaded.  Because `wait` is async, your call just puts `wait` on the list of things to do when the app goes idle.  Your loop never goes idle.

Comment: @TimRoberts Close.  It's not because `wait` is async, but rather is because `wait` contains an `await` within it, and the assignment follows that `await`.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Well friend, this happens because the "await()" function returns a promise, which doesn't give time to update the variable to "updated". For that, you need to make the function "f()" as asynchronous also waiting for the execution of the function "await()" with the use of the reserved word "await", as follows:

```
async function f() {
    await wait();
    // rest of the function...
}
```

That way you can avoid the infinite loop.

Good luck.

Comment: But that defeats the original purpose of running the loop for a certain amount of time. Because the loop will break after the first iteration ...

Comment: In that case, you need to reformulate your friend logic.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript's runtime is single-threaded and based on an event loop that runs to completion, meaning each item in the event loop's queue needs to be completed before the next one can be processed (the loop as a whole, rather than the individual iterations, is a single item in that queue).

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Event_loop#run-to-completion):

> Each message is processed completely before any other message is processed.
>
> This offers some nice properties when reasoning about your program, including the fact that whenever a function runs, it cannot be preempted and will run entirely before any other code runs (and can modify data the function manipulates). This differs from C, for instance, where if a function runs in a thread, it may be stopped at any point by the runtime system to run some other code in another thread.
>
> A downside of this model is that if a message takes too long to complete, the web application is unable to process user interactions like click or scroll. The browser mitigates this with the "a script is taking too long to run" dialog. A good practice to follow is to make message processing short and if possible cut down one message into several messages.

This means that in your code, the `while` loop blocks the event loop, preventing any other operation queued (such as the promise resolution from the `wait` function) to be executed.

This is also one of the reasons why [`setTimeout`'s delay is not guaranteed (they might actually take longer)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout#late_timeouts).

This series of posts might be a better start to understand that than the MDN documentation IMO: [✨♻️ JavaScript Visualized: Event Loop](https://dev.to/lydiahallie/javascript-visualized-event-loop-3dif)

**⏳ Run loop for fixed amount of time:**

If what you want is to run the loop for a certain amount of time, you can do that in both a sync (blocking) and async (non-blocking) way.

You'll notice some differences in both responsiveness of the page while the loop is running as well as how many iterations you are able to run within a specific timeframe.

**Run loop for fixed amount of time - Blocking:**

```js
const msToRun = 2000 // 2 seconds

const t0 = performance.now() // or Date.now()

let iterations = 0

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(`This won't be logged until the loop is over.`)
}, 0)

while ((performance.now() - t0) < msToRun) {
    ++iterations
}

console.log(`Loop run for ${ iterations } iterations.`)
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

body:hover {
  background: yellow;
}
```

**Run "loop" for fixed amount of time - Non-blocking (setInterval):**

```js
const msToRun = 2000 // 2 seconds

const t0 = performance.now() // or Date.now()

let iterations = 0

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(`This will be logged before the loop is over.`)
}, 0)

const intervalID = setInterval(() => {
  ++iterations
  
  if (performance.now() - t0 >= msToRun) {
    clearInterval(intervalID)
    
    console.log(`Loop run for ${ iterations } iterations.`)
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

body:hover {
  background: yellow;
}
```

**Run "loop" for fixed amount of time - Non-blocking (setTimeout):**

```js
const msToRun = 2000 // 2 seconds

const t0 = performance.now() // or Date.now()

let iterations = 0

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(`This will be logged before the loop is over.`)
}, 0)

function runIteration() { 
  ++iterations
  
  if (performance.now() - t0 < msToRun) setTimeout(runIteration)
  else console.log(`Loop run for ${ iterations } iterations.`)
}

runIteration()
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

body:hover {
  background: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a loop that ends when a global variable is set to a certain value from outside of the loop, you must introduce an element of asynchronousness into the loop, so that the outside world gets a chance to modify the global variable. The following example uses a function that recursively invokes itself after 100ms. (You could also use a delay of 0ms, but a `setTimeout` or similar must be involved.)

```js
var a = "original";
setTimeout(function() {
  a = "updated";
}, 1000);

function loop() {
  console.log(a);
  if (a === "original") setTimeout(loop, 100);
}
loop();
```

Note that replacing the recursion with

```js
if (a === "original") Promise.resolve().then(loop);
```

is not "asynchronous enough" to allow the `setTimeout(..., 1000)` to finish in between.

Comment: That's because `setTimeout` is a macrotask, while the promise is a microtask. When `Promise.resolve().then(loop)` is executed, a new microtask is added to the microtask queue, and tasks from it will keep getting executed until it is empty and allows the event loop to start over and pick a new macrotask.

Answer (score 0):

As described in several answers, the nature of the problem is that JavaScript is single threaded, and asynchronous code blocks, such as code referenced by a Promise's `then()` or all code following an `await`, are queued up to be individually run once a prior process has completed, and in this case your parent process never completes.

For added clarity, I'm rewriting your code a little to provide two different scenarios, the first of which runs as to completion, whereas the second loops endlessly.  I've removed the timer, as it is irrelevant.

```
async function wait1() {
    new Promise(resolve => {});
    glb = "updated1";
}

async function wait2() {
    await new Promise(resolve => {});
    glb = "updated2";
}

function f(ver) {
    if (ver==1) {
        wait1();
    } else {
        wait2();
    }
    var glb2 = "original";
    while (glb2 == "original") {
        glb2 = glb;
        console.log("####  glb:" + glb, "ver:" + ver);
    }
    console.log("#### DONE  glb:" + glb, "ver:" + ver);
}

let glb = "original";
f(1);
glb="original";
f(2);
```

Note that the difference between `wait1` and `wait2` is that `wait2` awaits its Promise before assigning a new value to glb.  It doesn't really matter that either `wait1` or `wait2` function is declared `async`.  An `async` function is still immediately run to completion-- it just converts its return value to a `Promise`.  What gets you, in this case, is that all code following your `await`, including your assignment of `glb = "updated";`, is suspended and your function immediately returns an unfulfilled `Promise`.  That suspended code must wait in line behind the next available process, which happens to be the continuation of your `f` function.

To sum up, because your assignment `glb = "updated";` followed an `await`, it is suspended and not run until your `f()` function completes, which never happens.